# Multi-platform cloud base password manager

Tags: windows, macos, iphone, password-management

I'm looking for a password manager working on Windows, Mac OS X and iPhone.

The password would be stock in the cloud so if I had a password into my iPhone it would automatically sync my PC and my Mac and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an up-and-coming feature of the excellent [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password). While the app is currently in [Beta for Windows](http://support.agilewebsolutions.com/showthread.php?23358-Installing-1Password-for-Windows), there are clients for Mac, iPhone and iPad already. And, once the [Dropbox](https://www.getdropbox.com/referrals/NTc5OTAwOQ) synchronization (via the Dropbox API) is complete and available via the App Store, you'll get your wish (as will I and many others as well).

I don't like to recommend apps based on features they don't yet have, so I'd wait for the Dropbox sync to be finalized if the 'cloud' aspect is essential to your needs.

Comment: This would be great!!!

Comment: It seems that the feature has been implemented now! I'm just thinking about paying the application.

Comment: I'm using now 1Password since 18 month and I must say it's totally awesome! Before I really had problem to gather all my login in one place, but now it's fixed and I was able to increase my password complexity. I recommand!!!

Answer (score 0):

[LastPass](https://lastpass.com/) is well worth investigating.